# Why does Dropbox upload in bursts?

Tags: dropbox, synchronization, upload

When Dropbox uploads files, it does not sustain a constant speed.
The upload happens in bursts, stopping for a few seconds every few seconds.

Other apps, such as CloudApp or Google Drive, or even ftp, upload consistently.

This is a traffic graph of Dropbox uploading:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether Dropbox is classified as a "web application" or a "desktop application" - this site's distinction between "web applications" and "desktop applications" is very confusing and arbitrary, so I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site this question belongs on Superuser or Webapps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Dropbox's drive synchronization feature, not its web interface.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because the Dropbox client uploads files in 4 MB chunks.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api : "A typical chunk is 4 MB."

Comment: That makes sense. I tested a straight upload to Dropbox, and that did go at full speed. I guess syncing is slower than uploading. Bummer.